# Vscode goto definition or show references loading indefinitely

Tags: vscode-extensions

The goto definition or show references keeps loading indefinitely.

I have installed the C/C++ extension. Tried enabling and disabling it multiple times, uninstalling the extension and reinstalling it multiple times(also tried modifying settings.json), tried older versions, and went through the questions online without any luck.
The Python extension works fine for python code intellisense but the C/C++ does not seem to work for C code.

Any help would be appreciated.

edit: should also mention I am using ssh into a remote linux host from the vscode app on widows.

Answer (score 0):

You have to MinGW GCC for C and C++. Firstly, you download MinGW and then follow the following steps:

1. Open Environment Variables
2. In System Variable select Path -> Edit -> New
3. Copy this C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin to the New window. (If you have MinGW installed copy its /bin path).
4. To check if you have added it successfully: Open CMD -> Type "gcc" and it should return: gcc: fatal error: no input files compilation terminated.
5. Install C/C++ for Visual Studio Code && C/C++ Compile Run || Code Runner
6. If you installed only C/C++ Compile Run extension you can compile your program using F6/F7
7. If you installed the second extension you can compile your program using the button in the top bar.